# mousedown event fired but not click event when I click on a absolutely positioned and higher z-index <li> item - possibly CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

When I tap (on mac touchpad) on a dropdown list(second list) item on the [page][1], I can select the item.
When I click with a mouse or click on my touchpad, I can't select the item.
What did I do wrong? It could be my CSS problem?
It works if I change (click) to (mousedown). How does the event propagation work here? Thanks

This is the html snippet.

```
 <div role='Listbox' (keyup)='handleKeyUpEvent($event)' (keydown)='handleKeyDownEvent($event)'>
   <span tabIndex='1' (blur)='listBlur()' (click)='listActivated()'
    (click)='toggleDropDownList()'
    [ngClass]='titleClasses'>{{title || 'DropDownList'}}</span>
     <ul role='List' [ngClass]='listClasses'>
       <li
         role='Listitem'
         (mousedown)='selectItem(item)'
         *ngFor='let item of listItems; let i = index'
         [class.selected]='i === activeIndex'
         [selected]='i === activeIndex'>{{i + 1}}: {{item.data}}
       </li>
     </ul>
   <span [ngClass]='clearClasses' (click)='deselectItem()'>Clear</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself** better still provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your `drop-down-list.component.html`, you have a `blur` event on your dropdown element. This is causing your list to close before your mouse click event gets fired on the list (removing the event as a test resolves the issue). It inconsistently happens due to a race condition.

Easiest (and clumsiest) way to solve this is to add a timeout to your `listBlur` method to give the click event time to fire.

Best way to solve this would be to not close the list on blur if the mouse cursor is inside/over the dropdown list. And then the click event should close the list itself.

Comment: I see, Thanks! I would give it a try and report back.
On another note, If I don't listen to blur event, how to click outside of the dropdown list to close it?

Comment: You should still listen to the blur event, the `listBlur` method that gets called should either contain a timeout before closing the list or it should check if the mouse is hovering the dropdown list and not close the list if it is. Definitely not suggesting removing the event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about using a mousedown instead of click as with mousedown, it works as intended. Is doing that a clumsy way?

Comment: @Jun, firing an event on `mousedown` is generally not the preferred way of doing things. Sometimes a person might click on an item and, while still holding down the mouse, decide it's the wrong item, move the mouse off of the item and then release the mouse (rare case but it happens). It's a bad UX to immediately take the click event while the user still has the mouse button held down.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not actually due to touch vs. click. If you click fast enough then it does actually work.

The problem is that the menu is disappearing on mousedown, so if you don't mouseup quickly enough then there's no element on which to register the click!

There's too much going on in your CSS for me to follow but I think that's where the problem lies. What code have you added to clear the drop-down away as soon as an item is clicked on?

Sorry it's not a complete answer but this might at least lead you to the cause. It's definitely **not** a fundamental failing of the click event.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's why tap on the touchpad works as it fires the event fast enough compared to a click(mouseup and mousedown).

Comment: Sort of. Touching the mousepad does not generate a mousedown, but it does generate a click if released quickly enough without movement. So you get a click without needing to be fast. Whereas the mouse or explicit touchpad click *do* generate mousedown so you've got to release it quickly!

Comment: Raith, touching the mousepad does generate a mousedown and a mouseup events

Comment: Sorry, yes. It *does* generate a mousedown, mouseup and click event, but **all at the same time** and only **if** it registers a click. The mousedown does not fire when you touch on. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be1xq3w9/2/) (outputs to the console)

Comment: Raith, on my chrome version 64.0.3282, it fires 3 on the console. What browser are you using? It could be browser and system dependent.

Comment: Same version as you. I agree that it fires all 3 events. But when touching the mousepad it only generates them when releasing a click. Mousedown = mouseup = click. Whereas when pressing the mousepad it generates a mousedown immediately and a mouseup on release (but only generates a click if the mouseup is still over the same element). The behaviour is different for touch vs. press. If you don't perform a quick touch then you get no events at all. Are you seeing the same or different to me?